# error with coffeescript when I use update method with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, coffeescript, insert-update

```
mongo = require 'mongodb' 
server = new mongo.Server "127.0.0.1", 27017, {}

client = new mongo.Db 'test', server, {w:1}

order = (dbErr, collection) ->
    console.log "Unable to access database: #{dbErr}" if dbErr
    collection.update({ _id:'2122129'},{'$set':{'status':'done'}}).nextObject (err, result) ->
      if err
          console.log "Unable to find record: #{err}"
      else
          console.log result 
      client.close()

client.open (err, database) ->
    client.collection 'order', order
```

error message:

> Unable to access database: Error: writeConcern requires callback
>   /Users/radjiv/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:298
>          throw err;
>                   ^ TypeError: Cannot call method 'update' of undefined

I try to run my script but something is wrong, and I don't have no ideas how to fix it. I have this error message, if someone can help me. i'm still a beginner. thank you

Comment: It seems that you have not yet connected to your db and you are trying to update something on the connection.

Comment: hum...ok but when I replace collection.update by collection.find() my script works

Comment: Why are you calling `nextObject` on the return value of `update` (which is always `null`)?  Looks like you should be providing that anonymous function as the third parameter to your `update` call instead.

Comment: yes you're right I made a mistake there thanks to put on the good way `order= (dbErr, collection) ->
    console.log "Unable to access database: #{dbErr}" if dbErr
    
    collection.update({ _id:'2122129'},{'$set':{'status':'done'}},  (err, result) ->
      if err
        console.log "Unable to find record: #{err}"
      else
        console.log result
      client.close()
    )`

Comment: Can you edit your question instead of putting the new info in a comment?

Answer (score 0):

```
mongo = require 'mongodb'
#connection to the server
server = new mongo.Server "127.0.0.1", 27017, {}

#select the database
client = new mongo.Db 'test', server, {w:1}

client.open (err, database) ->
  client.collection 'order', order

#update the collection 
order = (dbErr, collection) ->
  console.log "Unable to access database: #{dbErr}" if dbErr
  #change the status
  collection.update({ _id:'2122129'},{'$set':{'status':'done'}}, (err, result) ->
    if err
      console.log "Unable to find record: #{err}"
    else
      console.log result
      client.close()
  )
```

I found a solution and it's working, I post my solution if someone have the same problem